# TypeError: Cannot find function findIndex in object

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the row position of a string in a google sheets doc. Here is the code I'm using to attempt to do it:

```
var searchString = channelName;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ChannelViews"); 
var column = 1;
var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString);
return searchResult;
```

The full error I get is:

`TypeError: Cannot find function findIndex in object ,,,,,,,,,ESPN,.`

Currently, my spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see up to two issues:

1. [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) expects a callback function, not a string. You may have meant to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
2. If you *did* mean to use `findIndex` and just forgot to fill in the function: Unfortunately, Google Apps Script is not quite JavaScript, and in particular the standard library is quite far behind the standard library in recent versions of JavaScript. `Array.prototype.findIndex` was introduced in ES2015 (aka "ES6"). You can find a polyfill for it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (although I don't know if the usual polyfill practices work with GAS).

Comment: `indexOf` is working, but now I'm getting `-1` as the result when performing the search. `columnValues` is `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [ESPN], []]`, but when I do `var searchResult = columnValues.indexOf([searchString]);`, I still get `-1`

Comment: I decided to manually search the 2d array, and it's working now

Comment: @db2791: Good deal. `.indexOf([anything])` will always return -1, because that object by definition is freshly-created and isn't in the array. Remember that two different objects (or arrays) are never `==` or `===` to each other: `([] == [])` is false, as is `({} == {})`.